# how to call inline asm which returns 2 values in LLVM 3.2

Tags: assembly, llvm

In C++, we can let a inline asm to return 2 values, like:

```
ulonglong2 ThreadLoad<cub_modifier, ulonglong2*>(ulonglong2* ptr)
{
    ulonglong2 retval;
    asm volatile ("ld."#ptx_modifier".v2.u64 {%0, %1}, [%2];"
        "=l"(retval.x),
        "=l"(retval.y) :
        _CUB_ASM_PTR_(ptr));
    return retval;
}
```

how can we create LLVM IR for this usage? I have tried:

```
%3 = alloca { i32, i32 }, align 8
%40 = getelementptr inbounds { i32, i32 }* %38, i64 %39
%41 = getelementptr inbounds { i32, i32 }* %3, i32 0, i32 0
%42 = getelementptr inbounds { i32, i32 }* %3, i32 0, i32 1
call void asm sideeffect alignstack "ld.cg.v2.u32 \09{$0, $1}, [$2];", "=l,=l,l"(i32* %41, i32* %42, { i32, i32 }* %40)
%43 = load { i32, i32 }* %3, align 8
```

And this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a toy example of your problem:

```
struct ulonglong2
{
        unsigned long long x;
        unsigned long long y;
};

ulonglong2 ThreadLoad(ulonglong2* ptr)
{
    ulonglong2 retval;
    asm volatile ("ld.cg.v2.u64 {%0, %1}, [%2];" : "=l"(retval.x), "=l"(retval.y) : "l" (ptr));
    return retval;
}
int main() {

    ulonglong2 val;
    ulonglong2 x = ThreadLoad(&val);
    return 0;
}
```

and let clang emit the LLVM IR (command: `clang -emit-llvm test.cpp -c -S -o ptx.ll`):

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define { i64, i64 } @_Z10ThreadLoadP10ulonglong2(%struct.ulonglong2* %ptr) #0 {
  %1 = alloca %struct.ulonglong2, align 8
  %2 = alloca %struct.ulonglong2*, align 8
  store %struct.ulonglong2* %ptr, %struct.ulonglong2** %2, align 8
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.ulonglong2* %1, i32 0, i32 0
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.ulonglong2* %1, i32 0, i32 1
  %5 = load %struct.ulonglong2** %2, align 8
  %6 = call { i64, i64 } asm sideeffect "ld.cg.v2.u64 $($0, $1$), [$2];", "=l,=l,l,~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"(%struct.ulonglong2* %5) #1, !srcloc !1
  %7 = extractvalue { i64, i64 } %6, 0
  %8 = extractvalue { i64, i64 } %6, 1
  store i64 %7, i64* %3, align 8
  store i64 %8, i64* %4, align 8
  %9 = bitcast %struct.ulonglong2* %1 to { i64, i64 }*
  %10 = load { i64, i64 }* %9, align 1
  ret { i64, i64 } %10
}
```

The line that maters:

```
  %6 = call { i64, i64 } asm sideeffect "ld.cg.v2.u64 $($0, $1$), [$2];", "=l,=l,l,~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"(%struct.ulonglong2* %5) #1, !srcloc !1
```

Your asm call needs `{i64, i64}` as return type and just takes one input parameter (since you only declare one in your asm line). Everything else is strait forward. Taking the pointers where to store the two `ulonglong` values and store it. Everything after `%9` is just to return the values as struct. If you pass `-O3` to clang you will see that everything but the asm call disappears and the pointer is directly forwarded to the asm call.